# C# htmlelement combined with variable

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of table cells that I have given  a runat='server' attribute and they are structured with their id's looking like "cell_0", "cell_1", "cell_2" etc

I am trying to do a for loop to assign innertext to each of these programmatically but I cant seem to figure out how to add the variable into the name when looping..see code

```
       protected void Last_Updated()
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dbase.Length; i++)
                    {

HtmlTableCell elem = (HtmlTableCell)this.Page.FindControl("lastup_" + i.ToString() + "");
                        elem.InnerText = filemodDate("C:\somefile").ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
                    }

                }
```

how would I do this to make the `cell_[i]` convert represent the html element to set its innertext?

thanks

Comment: I started writing an answer to this, then a realised your entire logic is flawed. My advice, delete everything, learn ASP.Net better and try again.

Comment: @Liam after re-reading the question, I think you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = (HtmlTableCell)FindControl("cell_" + i.ToString());
elem.InnerText = "yada yada";
```

Are those cells are in a repeater item template or just a table?

Comment: thank you to someone who answered the question. it works